# TS Pick type based on nested type's keys

Tags: typescript, types, typing

Given a type defined by nested types all containing a key `label`

```
type Payloads = {
    EventA: { label: 'Foo', content: object }
    EventB: { label: 'Bar', content: object }
    EventC: { label: 'Baz', content: object }
}
```

And a type defined as the union of select potential `label` types

```
type SelectLabels = 'Foo' | 'Bar'
```

How can I create a type defined as only the keys of `Payloads` whose value type has a `label` key whose value type is a member of `SelectLabels`, resulting in the following behavior:

```
function f(x: TypeGoesHere) {}
f('EventA') // OK
f('EventB') // OK
f('EventC') // Error
```

I've tried the following

```
type TypeGoesHere = Pick<keyof Payloads, Payloads[keyof Payloads]['label'][SelectLabels]>
```

but get the following error:

```
Property 'Bar' does not exist on type '"Foo" | "Bar" | "Baz"'.ts(2339)
Property 'Foo' does not exist on type '"Foo" | "Bar" | "Baz"'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: `keyof { [K in keyof Payloads as Payloads[K]["label"] extends SelectedLabels ? K : never]: K }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Payloads = {
    EventA: { label: 'Foo', content: object }
    EventB: { label: 'Bar', content: object }
    EventC: { label: 'Baz', content: object }
}

type SelectLabels = 'Foo' | 'Bar'

// similar to Object.entries
type Entries<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [key: K, value: T[K]] }[keyof T]

type TypeGoesHere = Extract<Entries<Payloads>, [any, { label: SelectLabels }]>[0]
//   ^?
//   type TypeGoesHere = "EventA" | "EventB"

type Explain1 = Entries<Payloads>
//   ^?
//   ['EventA', {label: 'Foo, ...}] | ['EventB', { label: 'Bar', ...}] | ['EventC', { label: 'Baz', ...}]
// same as Object.entries for runtime

type Explain2 = Extract<Entries<Payloads>, [any, { label: SelectLabels }]>
//   ^?
//   ["EventA", { label: 'Foo', ... }] | ["EventB", { label: 'Bar', ... }]
// pick tuples where value (second item) matches { label: SelectLabels }

type Explain3 = Explain2[0]
//   ^?
//   "EventA" | "EventB"
// take first element of every tuple
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @jcalz you's welcome to remind me about that